# what difference 'by lazy' between '= lazy' in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

i want to know what difference 'by lazy' between '= lazy' in kotlin

```
val host by lazy { ... }
```

```
val host = lazy { ... }
```

in my android code

```
val host by lazy {
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
}
```

has succeed

but this code

```
val host = lazy {
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
}
```

has failed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
val host by lazy { ... }
```

This means that host property is a property enhanced by [Kotlin's lazy delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy). Its value will be calculated only once when it is first accessed. Following calls only return cached result of the first call.

```
val host = lazy { ... }
```

This on the other hand means that instead of host property being enhanced by delegate it contains a lazy delegate. Since it contains the delegate object, you can access its methods such as [isInitialized()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-lazy/is-initialized.html) or access [value](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-lazy/value.html) of the delegate which will trigger its computation.

Consider following example:

```
val host = lazy {
    println("computed!")
    "Hello"
}

fun main() {
    println(host)
    println(host.value)
    println(host)
}
```

Here we have a lazy delegate `host`. If you try to print its value you will get: **"Lazy value not initialized yet."**. But once you access its value it behaves the same as with `by lazy {...}`

Answer (score 8):

The `lazy { ... }` part specifies a function that returns a `Lazy<T>`.

If you just say `val foo = lazy { "bar" }`, then any get or set operation will operate on the `Lazy<String>` instance.

When you use `val foo by lazy { "bar" }`, you're telling the compiler to *delegate* any get or set operation on `foo` to the `String`.

---

If we have this:

```
class Test {
    val usingAssign = lazy {
        "bar"
    }

    val usingBy by lazy {
        "bar"
    }
}
```

and we look at the corresponding Java code it will look something like this:

```
private final Lazy usingAssign;
private final Lazy usingBy$delegate;

public final Lazy getUsingAssign() {
   return this.usingAssign;
}

public final String getUsingBy() {
   Lazy var1 = this.usingBy$delegate;
   KProperty var3 = $$delegatedProperties[0];
   return (String)var1.getValue();
}

public Test() {
   this.usingAssign = LazyKt.lazy((Function0)null.INSTANCE);
   this.usingBy$delegate = LazyKt.lazy((Function0)null.INSTANCE);
}
```

So any attempt to read `usingBy` would give us a `String`, which we then could e.g. assign to another `String` variable. You can't do that with `usingAssign`, because its type is `Lazy<String>`.

Answer (score 4):

`by lazy` means, that the logic will be executed upon the first use

> lazy properties: the value gets computed only upon first access

when you use

```
val host = lazy {
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
}
```

you basically assign lazy property to the host variable. So it becomes `Lazy<Something>`, from which you can take value or check if its initialized.

`by lazy {"test"}` -> gives `String`

`= lazy { "test" }` -> gives `Lazy<String>`